# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'xxx' and 'xxx'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a function call in `useEffect`  hook Below is the code

```
const getAggregatedBasketList = (values) => {
  API.getAggregatedBaskets({
    basketType: "",
    tagSearch: tags,
    isLoggedIn: auth.isAuthenticated,
    limit: null,
    titleOrTagSearch: values.searchString,
    isSearch: true,
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      setSortedBaskets(data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      setBaskets([]);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getAggregatedBasketList(formik.values);
}, [tags]);
```

I am getting the error

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'formik.values' and 'getAggregatedBasketList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

the function `getAggregatedBasketList` is being called from another hook also, so I can not put that in `useEffect` hook.

`formik.values` is changing for each input and I do not want to add it in dependency array otherwise the function will be called for each input.

How to disable the warning

I can add `// eslint-disable-next-line` but is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: You can just call `getAggregatedBasketList(formik.values)` wherever you are updating your `tags`. We might not need a useEffect here.